# how to remove schema ownerships from orphaned users when schema doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where a database was restored from one instance into a new one without bringing over the master db.   Consequently all security information is lost.  Oddly client can still access data via trusted connections but when attempting to do userid administration, you can not delete an account because it says it is owner of a schema. In the user databases you can get a long list of schemas for just about every user account of the same name.  A dump of sys.schema shows that none of these user schemas exist (obviously they would have been in the original instance's master database but not the new one).   Since the schema doesn't exist how do you make the userid disown a non-existing entity  so that it can in turn be deleted?

I have to this for 132 users so I am looking for a repetitive script as well.   Per research on this site I saw script to change owner to dbo but in that situation the schema  existed.   In my situation it doesn't.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Found the bad references in sys.sysusers to sys.schemas in the target db. Use <Target DB>

Answer (score 1):

One of two things might be going on:

1. You might be checking `sys.schemas` in a different database.  The schemas might exist in the target database, but if you're selecting from `sys.schemas` in `master`, you'll get different results.
2. Schemas do not have to have the same name as the database user that owns them.

To clean this up, I would use the following code/approach:

Create a .txt file of your user names, each user on a different line.

Use the following SQL code:

```
use [copied_db];

CREATE TABLE #users
(uname varchar(100));

BULK INSERT #users FROM 'C:\test\users.txt';

SELECT 'DROP SCHEMA ' + QUOTENAME(s.name,'[') + ';'
FROM #users u
    JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON (u.uname = dp.name)
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON (dp.principal_id = s.principal_id);

SELECT 'DROP USER ' + QUOTENAME(dp.name,'[') + ';'
FROM #users u
    JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON (u.uname = dp.name);
```

This code will provide you with the drop statements for the individual actions so you can run them at your discretion.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem was in the target db and I found it with two queries.  Your routine will be very helpful in cleaning up the garbage.  Identifying Queries are against sys.sysusers and sys.syschemas tying uid to principal_id for schema and you see the relationships and what you have to change.